ERROR: failed to register layer: Error processing tar file(exit status 1)
When I am running Localstack then I am getting the error:

PS D:\Localstack> docker-compose up Pulling localstack
(localstack/localstack:latest)... latest: Pulling from
localstack/localstack e4fff0779e6d: Already exists                    
d97016d0706d: Already exists                                          
53db1713e5d9: Already exists                                          
a8cd795d9ccb: Already exists                                          
de3ba92de392: Already exists                                          
048f50fe308f: Pull complete                                           
4542e2f6b62e: Pull complete                                           
01822b90a867: Pull complete                                           
f88d1e903ef2: Pull complete                                           
6284d3eed9c9: Pull complete                                           
bf8eb48c6700: Pull complete                                           
8b00183573da: Pull complete                                           
4f4fb700ef54: Pull complete                                           
5d850abf78b3: Pull complete                                           
12ff95b82ae3: Pull complete                                           
e173c56a9dc6: Pull complete                                           
ae7a9c1d239f: Pull complete                                           
3095282ba342: Pull complete                                           
54e29c63ac7e: Extracting
[==================================================>]    129MB/129MB  
72f9a0d4296a: Download complete                                       
49c58d119219: Download complete                                       
a1d9a02c5b38: Download complete                                       
76b820554a94: Download complete                                       
94bcc574166a: Download complete                                       
7878ab22a709: Download complete                                       
66384fec2e8e: Download complete                                       
c150844d7129: Download complete                                       
c147c067fef2: Download complete                                       
ERROR: failed to register layer: Error processing tar file(exit status
1): write
/opt/code/localstack/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/twisted/logger/__pycache__/_filter.cpython-311.pyc: no space left on device

Answer https://docs.localstack.cloud/references/configuration/
DOCKER_SOCK   /var/run/docker.sock    Path to local Docker UNIX domain
socket


The full compose file is here:
version: '3.1'

services: 

  localstack:
    image: localstack/localstack:latest
    environment: 
      - AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
      - EDGE_PORT=4566
      - SERVICES=lambda,s3
    ports: 
      - '4566-4583:4566-4583'
    volumes: 
      - "${TEMPDIR:-/tmp/localstack}:/tmp/localstack"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"

I tried changing Localstack version several times and using different ports, but the error is the same.

Remove all other container
   docker rm <container_id>

Remove all images
   docker rmi -f $(docker image ls -a -q)

Then run your compose file

You are running out of space dedicated for docker images on your device, you may need to prune some old images/volumes, or expand size allocated to Docker. Docker Desktop allows you to change the size of the disc in the GUI. Go to Preferences->Resources->Advanced and adjust Virtual Disk limit to increase the disc image size.
Otherwise, you can run a clean-up on your environment:
Docker Prune
